# Python Tkinter xscrollbar not working

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm almost at the point of tearing my hair out over this one:

I'm trying to get an xscrollbar and yscrollbar working so that I can move around a large canvas in Tkinter. The reason I'm so frustrated is because the yscrollbar seems to be working WITH THE EXACT SAME CODE (replacing x with y everywhere). Here's what I have:

```
master = Tk()
scrolly = Scrollbar(master,orient = VERTICAL)
scrollx = Scrollbar(master,orient = HORIZONTAL)
scrollx.pack(side = TOP,fill = X)
scrolly.pack(side = RIGHT,fill = Y)
w = Canvas(master, width=1000,height=1000,yscrollcommand = scrolly.set,xscrollcommand = scrollx.set,scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))
s = Scale(master,from_= 0, to=len(worldlist)-1,orient = HORIZONTAL,length = 595)
s.pack(side = BOTTOM)
w.pack()
setSys(worldlist[0],master,w)
def show(self):
    w.delete(ALL)
    setSys(worldlist[s.get()],master,w)
s.config(command = show)
scrolly.config(command = w.yview)
scrollx.config(command = w.xview)
mainloop()
```

I want the canvas and a scale widget sitting at the bottom. And at the right and top, a ybar and an xbar, respectively. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm quite desperate for some help!

Thanks!

Gabe

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does that mean it appears, but dragging it has no effect?

Comment: The bar that surrounds the scrollbar appears horizontally on the top, but it does't have a scrollbar in it.

Comment: @BryanOakley Seems like the bar in greyed out, after trying the code he's got posted

Comment: On my machine this works as expected. The window it creates is 1000 pixels wide and you're setting the scrollregion to be 100 pixels wide, so there's nothing that needs a horizontal scrollbar. Are you sure the problem isn't simply that your application is sufficiently wide that a scrollbar isn't necessary? If you resize the window to be narrower, does the scrollbar become active for you?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the xbar isn't working is because it's got nothing to scroll *to*. After you configure the canvas to a size bigger than the screen, it starts working. Take a look at the following code to see where I've added the `scrollregion` config. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/ScrolledCanvas.htm

```
from Tkinter import * 

def show(self):
    w.delete(ALL)
    setSys(worldlist[s.get()],master,w)

master = Tk()

scrolly = Scrollbar(master,orient = VERTICAL)
scrollx = Scrollbar(master,orient = HORIZONTAL)
scrollx.pack(side = TOP,fill = X)
scrolly.pack(side = RIGHT,fill = Y)

w = Canvas(master, width=500, height=500, yscrollcommand = scrolly.set,
           xscrollcommand = scrollx.set, scrollregion=(0,0,1000,1000))
w.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 5000))
w.pack()

s = Scale(master,from_= 0, to=100-1,orient = HORIZONTAL,length = 595)
s.pack(side = BOTTOM)
s.config(command = show)


scrolly.config(command = w.yview)
scrollx.config(command = w.xview)


mainloop()
```